# Update manager doesnt offer app updates

Tags: 12.04, updates

I currently use libreoffice 3.5 and I want to update to 3.6.
I know that the update manager also updates apps so I tried to update libreoffice through the update manager but the update manager didnt show any update available for libreoffice.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the package lists and update all packages from the terminal, you can run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this still doesn't give you the newest version of libreoffice, the repositories probably have not been updated with the newest version yet.

You may want to add the repository for LibreOffice to get the latest versions as quickly as possible. Instructions for this taken from [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice):

Open a terminal. Run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

This will add the LibreOffice repository permanently to your list of repositories to check for new versions. Run this to update the repo lists and upgrade all new packages:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, if libreoffice came with ubuntu preinstalled you would think that the repository for it would come with it too. oh well

Comment: LibreOffice is included in the normal repositories, they just don't update as quickly as LibreOffice's "own" repos :)

Comment: Also, please mark this as an answer if it answered your question.